# Spring Integration - header lost

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I'm new to Spring Integration and Spring Integration AMQP.

I have the following code:

```
<bean id="enricher" class="soft.Enricher"/>

<amqp:inbound-channel-adapter queue-names="QUEUE1" channel="amqpInboundChannel"/>

<int:channel id="amqpInboundChannel">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:header-enricher input-channel="amqpInboundChannel" output-channel="routingChannel">
        <int:header name="store" value="sj" />
</int:header-enricher>

<int:channel id="routingChannel" />

<int:header-value-router input-channel="routingChannel" header-name="store">
    <int:mapping value="sj" channel="channelSJ" />
    <int:mapping value="jy" channel="channelJY" />
</int:header-value-router>

<amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="channelSJ" exchange-name="ex_store" routing-key="sj" amqp-template="rabbitTemplate"/>
<amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="channelJY" exchange-name="ex_store" routing-key="jy" amqp-template="rabbitTemplate"/>

<int:channel id="channelSJ" />
<int:channel id="channelJY" />

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" level="ERROR" />
```

The setup is the following:

[image: My Setup]

Everything is working fine except that headers are lost when a message is picked up by the inbound-channel-adapter.

Likewise the header being enriched called "store" is also lost when the message is being send to the exchange using the outbound-channel-adapter.

This is how a message is looking before being picked up by the inbound-channel-adapter:

[image: Before]

This is how the same message is looking after the whole process (notice no headers)

[image: After]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your problem is described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/amqp.html):

"*By default only standard AMQP properties (e.g. contentType) will be copied to and from Spring Integration MessageHeaders. Any user-defined headers within the AMQP MessageProperties will NOT be copied to or from an AMQP Message unless explicitly identified via 'requestHeaderNames' and/or 'replyHeaderNames' properties of this HeaderMapper. If you need to copy all user-defined headers simply use wild-card character '*'.*"

So you need to define your own custom instance of `DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper` and configure the `inbound-channel-adapter` with it. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/api/org/springframework/integration/amqp/support/DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.html).

It might look something like this:

```
        <bean id="myHeaderMapper" class="org.springframework.integration.amqp.support.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper">
                    <property name="requestHeaderNames" value="*"/>
                    <property name="replyHeaderNames" value="*"/>
        </bean>

        <amqp:inbound-channel-adapter queue-names="QUEUE1" channel="amqpInboundChannel"
                                      header-mapper="myHeaderMapper"/>
```

Comment: It is just basic Spring configuration. Nothing magical. But I added something that should approximate what you want.

Comment: You can also use mapped-request-headers="*" on the adapapter.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Good luck on your project!